# Use fakeweb or webmock to simulate RestClient::GatewayTimeout in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, testunit, rest-client

I often see `RestClient::GatewayTimeout` in my application. I'm trying to figure out how to properly test for this, to make sure my application handles it gracefully.

The closest thing to this that I see is `stub_request(:any, 'www.example.net').to_timeout`

That raises `RestClient::RequestTimeout` however and not `RestClient::GatewayTimeout`. What's the best way to simulate the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stub_request(:any, 'www.example.net').to_raise(RestClient::GatewayTimeout)`

This will obviously work only for RestClient and if you change RestClient to
some other library, you'll have to change your test too.